Error 404 when trying to access an api module
I'm a new practitioner of next.js and am currently working through a project that connects openAI to PDFs. However, while working through the project I have come a cross a problem.
I've created an API module named create-chat, but when I try to access it at localhost:3000/api/create-chat, I get error 404 back, despite the URL being correct and the module obviously existing. So I am unsure of where my routing issue lies.
This is my create-chat/route.ts file:
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { chats } from "@/lib/db/schema";
import { loadS3IntoPinecone } from "@/lib/pinecone";
import { getS3Url } from "@/lib/s3";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// /api/create-chat
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { userId } = await auth();
  if (!userId) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
  }
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { file_key, file_name } = body;
    console.log(file_key, file_name);
    await loadS3IntoPinecone(file_key);
    const chat_id = await db
      .insert(chats)
      .values({
        fileKey: file_key,
        pdfName: file_name,
        pdfUrl: getS3Url(file_key),
        userId,
      })
      .returning({
        insertedId: chats.id,
      });

    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        chat_id: chat_id[0].insertedId,
      },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "internal server error" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}


I've tried creating a custom server.js file. I've verified that my path is correct. I've set up my Middleware config page as instructed to on Clerk's website... I'm at a loss at how to debug this error.

Considering the file has a POST func only, are you making a POST request or a GET? Code seems to be correct. What does your routing look like? API route should be placed like pages/api/create-chat/route.ts

I am making a Post request, but my console is loggin a GET request. I tried updating my code to use a GET request instead, but still ran into the same error.
I pushed my code into a github repository in order to get help here:
https://github.com/fnakasako/acacetatest
One second... Need to fix my repository

Unable to access the Repo still. Any luck? Fact that your doing a GET on the request won't even hit the POST request and lead to the 404, make sure you're making a POST request from your frontend.
